# Flutter Layout: Listview inside Row flexible height inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, listview, row, width

[EDIT Solution]: there was a missing expanded around the ListView that was causing problems and errors. Thanks to all for your valuable inputs and Happy Easter!

I am trying to obtain a layout as in the below image.
Inside a SingleChildScrollview, I have an overall row with two children inside:

1. A list of widgets [it can be a listview or a for(int i=0;i<...;i++) widget() ] whose height is unknown ant that it should take all the available width
2. A single button that should be vertically centered and taking as little space as possible.

[image: Desired Layout]

I have been trying out different solutions but I run in errors over errors as everything is inside a SingleChildScrollView and Expanded Widgets require a fixed height, which I don't have as I don't know the height of the list of widgets and IntrinsicHeight doesn't seem to work.

I also bumped into the boxy package ( https://pub.dev/documentation/boxy/latest/ ) which helped to solve to vertically center the iconbutton but there is still the problem about the list of widgets taking as much width as possible.

Recap of nested widgets

```
SingleChildScrollView(
 child: Column(
  children: [ ...,
   Row(
    children:[
     List of widgets, //should be taking as much width as possible but height is unknown
     IconButton() //should be vertically centered taking as little width as possible
     ]
    )
   ]
  )
)
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Thanks a lot in advance and happy Easter

Comment: do you want your list of items to be scrollable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's a list without many items, you can use an expanded together with shrinkWrap as true in the list, check if it's something like that you want

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Container(color: Colors.black, child: ListTile()),
                  Container(color: Colors.blue, child: ListTile()),
                  Container(color: Colors.yellow, child: ListTile()),
                  Container(color: Colors.black, child: ListTile()),
                  Container(color: Colors.grey, child: ListTile()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: (() {}),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the expanded widget around the listview that was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your `ListView` in `Expanded`. You don't need `SingleChildScrollView`, since `ListView` handles the scrolling.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item $i'),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the expanded widget around the listview that was missing!