# How to place horizontal scrollable Listview.builders inside a scrollable column? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-flexible

I would like to have a few horizontal scrollable rows which are going to be filled with data from a DB.

The Items in the row have unequal heights as some have 2 line text and some are only one-liners.

These rows should be displayed inside a scrollable column.

[image: This is how it should look like]

I found some related articles (linked below) and tried the solutions.

Please see the source-code below.

The problem is that the different rows are not really places below each other with their desired heights but are shrinked to fit on one screen. I think that this is because of the use of the SliverFillRemaining-Widget. But I don't know how to do it better.

[image: This is what it looks like with four sections]

[image: This is what it looks like with more sections]

Here is my current code:

The Code on the page:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Scroll-Element(),
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Scroll-Element(),
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Scroll-Element(),
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Scroll-Element(),
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Scroll-Element-Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                20, 0, 20, 0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Section",
                  style: cH2Style.copyWith(color: cTextColor),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: elements.length < 3 ? elements.length : 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final element = Element.fromDocument(elements[index]);
                return Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Element(),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Element-Code (the ones displayed in the Scroll-Element:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/testbild.jpg"),
            ),
          ),
          Text("..."),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Related articled:
[How to use Expanded in SingleChildScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview)

[Flutter Layout: Listview inside Row flexible height inside SingleChildScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978816/flutter-layout-listview-inside-row-flexible-height-inside-singlechildscrollview)

[4 Horizontal Listviews in a Scrollable Column in FLutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685849/4-horizontal-listviews-in-a-scrollable-column-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ListView in place of `CustomScrollView` like this,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return const Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Scroll-Element(),
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Scroll-Element(),
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Scroll-Element(),
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 1,
                child: Scroll-Element(),
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
              ),
            ],
          ),   
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, Feeling glad I was able to help you